# Amazon Linux with PHP7 and nginx doesn't load php

Tags: amazon-ec2, php-fpm, php7

Installing this on a fresh Amazon AWS micro instance with Amazon Linux. I've installed nginx and php7. I can't seem to get php to load.

> sudo yum install nginx
>   sudo yum install php70-fpm

Created a document root at:

> /var/www/html

User/Group is nginx:nginx

Edit php-fpm conf to point to correct user/group:

> /etc/php-fpm-7.0.d/www.conf

```
user = nginx
group = nginx

listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0664

listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock
```

Then I changed the default nginx conf

> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    index   index.php index.html index.htm;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         /var/www/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }


    }

}
```

If I create a php file at document root I just get a 404. Any html page loads fine. Nothing is in my error.log for nginx or php.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution. I was blind, this was in the error.log after all. Because I'm using sockets in the configuration:

> fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;

I missed another file that required the proper setting:

> /etc/nginx/conf.d/php-fpm.conf-7.0

```
upstream php-fpm {
        server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

Change to:

```
upstream php-fpm {
        server unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
}
```

Comment: tried but not working for me